# Keep getting 404 not found. Requested URL not found on websites

Tags: google-chrome, http-status-code-404

I am very confused to why this is happening (roast me if this is basic).
When I try to enter BBC news or my ebay account I keep getting this message.

> 404 Not Found The requested URL /news was not found on this server.

Also sometimes a box pops up asking me for login details a username and passowrd to get onto the BBC NEWS application
Please help I use a MAC and chrome

Answer (score 1):

May be there would be some proxy setup in your browser. Try to reach the site by disabling the proxy. And Test the internet connection by using some different browser and try to access different sites.

Also clean your browser history, cookies and cache it might help you.
And if it still doesn't work then uninstall the chrome - delete all installed files in

for windows the path is

> `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\`

then also delete the temporary files by typing

for windows the path is

> `%temp%`

in run **(Win + R)** and delete all files.
Then restart your PC and reinstall Chrome.
Hope now it would be fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, this also occurs in Safari so do you think that this must be a problem with my internet settings or antivirus? This randomly has occurred. Perhaps my internet connection?

Comment: Yes, then it simply means your internet is not working. Try to contact your ISP (Internet Service Provider) and tell them to fix the problem Internet is not working. Tell then it works sometimes then it doesn't and connectivity is not stable fix it. :))